# Error al grabar dentro de un For (Cuando itero)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Aquí tengo mi consulta, que uso en varias partes del programa.

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
```

Mi problema ahora es que cuando coloco la linea ---- self.run_query(query, parameters)----  dentro de for se bloquea la base de datos, me genera error, pero si la dejo afuera del for solo actualiza el ultimo registro. Acá la función.

```
def actualizar_estudiantes(self):
    miFecha=StringVar()
    miID1=StringVar()
    Fec_Act=datetime.datetime.today()
    query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela' 
    db_rows = self.run_query(query) 
    for database_escuela in db_rows:
        wdias=0
        miID1.set(database_escuela[0])
        miID = miID1.get()
        miFecha.set(database_escuela[6])
        Fec_Est = miFecha.get()
        Fec_est1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Fec_Est), '%d/%m/%Y')
        wdias=((Fec_Act - Fec_est1).days)
        query = 'UPDATE escuela SET DIAS1 = ? WHERE ID = ?'
        parameters = (wdias, miID)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
    messagebox.showinfo("A T E N C I O N ! ! !", "La lista de estudiantes se Actualizó Exitosamente")
```

Si coloco la linea ---- self.run_query(query, parameters)----adentro, ERROR DATABASE LOCKED,  si lo dejo afuera, solo actualizo la última línea, ¿pueden ayudarme o explicarme cómo debe actualizarse la línea y no se debe bloquear la base de datos? Por favor, llevo días con este problema. Gracias

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
     return self.func(*args)
   File "index5.py", line 206, in actualizar_estudiantes
     self.run_query(query, parameters)
   File "index5.py", line 106, in run_query
     conn.commit()
  sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: Alguien tiene idea de cual es mi error

Answer (score 0):

Cambia esta linea

```
return result
```

Prueba con esta linea

```
return [rec for rec in result]
```

Esta respuesta que me envió  stovfl funciono a perfección y resolvió el problema

Comment: Esta instrucción que envió stovfl  resolvió el problema, muchas gracias